# How does SMIE mode determine what the parent of a token is?

Tags: indentation, smie

I'm writing indentation rules for a custom mode using SMIE.

I want to use `smie-rule-parent-p` to have different behavior for indenting an empty line depending on context, so inside my indentation rules function, I have a case like this:

```
(`(:elem . empty-line-token)
     (if (smie-rule-parent-p ",") "," "---"))
```

(The `"---"` is a token that's always indented at column 0.)

The source language has definitions that look like this:

```
type Network = DC { reference_id    : ReferenceId
                  , inventory_class : InventoryClass
                  , children        : [Network]
                  }
```

when I start a new line in the middle of the `{ .. }` block, I want it indented in line with the commas:

```
type Network = DC { reference_id    : ReferenceId
                  , inventory_class : InventoryClass
                  , children        : [Network]
                  ^ -- I want the cursor here after indenting.
                  }
```

The rule using `smie-rule-parent-p ","` accomplishes this, but it also fires in other parts of the code. In fact, it even triggers *when there isn't a single comma in the whole buffer*.

How does SMIE determine what the parent of a token is? Can I use that to indent empty lines differently depending on context like I'm trying here?